# Line sweeping - what is it?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry

Can somebody try to explain to me what Line Sweeping is? I have basic knowledge in math and geometry. Please try to explain in language that I will most probably be able to understand.

Also, an coded example on how it can be implemented in some program (preferably Java) would be great.

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Check [@Josiah's link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm), but the idea is basically this:

"Sweep" a line through a space (probably 2D), and take some action whenever your encounter a point, vertex, or other object. You can use this to

- Construct a bounding shape around a point cloud
- Shrink wrap points to get a convex polygon,
- generating Voronoi diagrams (see example in the wiki link above)
- Perform primitive wave simulation (points encountered by the sweep line or wavefront will cause a disturbance in the shape of the wave)
- Visibility determination: pick a viewer location (or even multiple viewer locations) in on the starting sweep line. Each time you encounter an object, generate a cone or other volume from the viewer location through the outer bounds of the encountered object representing the area "behind" the encountered point.
- 2D / 3D sorting, though this would be far from the most efficient way to sort,
- Probably a whole slew of things I haven't thought of.

**Update**

For polygon intersection, you're better off using the [Separating Axis Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem). ([See this link](http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55) for Java examples.)

Also, [see this link](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-with-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169) for a less obfuscated overview of the algorithm.

Comment: I need this to check if two polygons (rectangles rotated) on the screen intersect. When I started working on a simple 2D game, I had no idea how much math and geometry I needed for this simple stuff :\

Comment: @user3150201 Ah - try the SAT. (See my update)

Comment: @user3150201 Also, the math gets easier with time. I typically wind up writing it once, then throwing it into a library (so you can call, say, `if( rectangle1.intesects(rectangle2) ) { .... }`. I'm teaching Math and Physics for Game Programers this Spring - there's a lot to it, but it's all learning curve (ie, it takes awhile to realize that it's not nearly as complex as it first seems). You don't have to be a mathematician; just patient.

Comment: Can you please direct me to a webpage where I can learn the basics of the geometry needed for 2D games? I don't know where to get the basics, after that I believe it will be easier.